# matching home age factors SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to produce the following result:

```
Table: [0070 Home Age Factor] 
Policy Number:    Home Age:      Home Age Factor:
100               31             1.1
101               35             1.1
102               42             1.15
```

From the rules below:

```
 Table: [Factor_HomeAge]
    Home Age:               Factor:
    New Construction        0.800
    1 to 5 years old        0.850
    6 to 10 years old       0.900
    11 to 15 years old      0.950
    16 to 20 years old      1.000
    21 to 30 years old      1.050
    31 to 40 years old      1.100
    over 40 years old       1.150
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT HWData.[Policy Number]
   , (DATEPART("YYYY", HWData.[Effective Date]) -
      HWData.[Year Built]) AS [Home Age]
   , Factor_HomeAge.Factor
FROM [0070 Home Age Factor] 
INNER JOIN Factor_HomeAge ON iif([0070 Home Age Factor].[Home Age] > 41, 41
   , [0070 Home Age Factor].[Home Age]) = Factor_HomeAge.[Home Age]
ORDER BY HWData.[Policy Number];
```

But it does not produce the result I want, can anyone help? I think I got inner join part incorrect. I want to use the table `Factor_HomeAge` to produce desire results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thinking there are a couple ways to go about this depending on the flexibility of your model and business rules.

1. Home_Age should list out every year from 0 to 100+ with the corresponding Factor value. If your business rules change and the factor for a range of years has to change it will be easier to maintain with a simple `UPDATE Factor_HomeAge SET Factor = <value> WHERE Home_Age BETWEEN <min> and <max>;` You could also include Effective and Expire dates if you wanted to retain a history.
2. Split the Home_Age into two columns: `Floor_Age` and `Ceiling_Age`. It's not as flexible as the previous solution because your ranges for a given factor may expand and/or collapse over time. This makes maintenance a little more difficult especially in the absence of Effective/Expire dates on the table. Your JOIN would behave more like a CROSS JOIN because you would J`OIN Home and Factor_HomeAge ON Home.Age BETWEEN Factor_HomeAge.Floor_Age and Factor_Home.Ceiling_Age`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Your JOIN would behave more like a CROSS JOIN" -- sounds more like a theta (inner) join to me.

Comment: Thinking through it a little more it probably would be more of an INNER JOIN. I didn't have something to mock up and test the query plan for the exact join strategy chosen. Thanks.